# How to add/ change meta tags specific to the Contacts page?

Tags: magento-1.9, meta-tags

I have a shopping store (www.goorganics.us) in Magento using the "Magento ver. 1.7.0.2". Please guide me how to update the Title and other Meta Tags (for SEO) of my Contacts page?

Answer (score 16):

The contact page comes from the module `Mage_Contats`.
To change the meta data you need to add this in `local.xml` layout file of your theme or inside the `contacts.xml` in the same theme.

```
<contacts_index_index>
    <reference name="head">
       <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>YOUR META TITLE HERE</title></action>
       <action method="setDescription" translate="description" module="contacts"><description>YOUR META DESCRIPTION HERE</description></action>
       <action method="setKeywords" translate="keywords" module="contacts"><keywords>YOUR META KEYWORDS HERE</keywords></action>
    </reference>
</contacts_index_index>
```

Comment: Just to note: if you choose to include this snippet in local.xml, it will break the layout of the contacts page. Best to do it in contacts.xml

Comment: I tried the above xml in my contacts.xml in my current theme (1.9.1) but its not updating, the title and meta.

Answer (score 1):

For Any CMS Page in Magento This is how you should update Meta Tags

Go to CMS -> Pages in Magento Admin

Click on the Page for Which you want to Update the Meta Tags from list  (Contact Page in Ur Case)
On The Left you Have Page Information Block ,

For Meta Title - Update your Page title. (Thats it)

For Keyword and Description tags 
Switch Meta Data Tab.

Here you have the Requisite Fields you can easily update. 

 Keyword and Description by default.

Its that easy. Cheers !!

Comment: What if there're pages where this isn't working? What would you suggest?

Comment: @versedi can you explain what are those pages ?? maybe in ur case. 
For any cms page, what i suggested would work, for module pages Marius' solution http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/35867/9676  will do

Comment: Yes you're right, I've accidently had override from System Configuration option turned on in my testing environment. So it's worth mentioning that you can't have a global description or it will not be overwriten by page's description. (P.S. Why isn't it working that way?)

Comment: @echoashu. It is required to verify website on  merchants.google.com after add meta ?

Comment: @SanjayGohil Meta Title & Descriptions will be auto fetched by google when it wud next crawl your website. 
I wud say it is not required to "re-verify" after updating meta-descriptions / title as they wud keep updating.