# How to identify pages and set meta info in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-1.7, meta-tags, cms-pages

I have some pages in my magento store which are not CMS Pages. 
They have phtml files and common head.html files. 
This pages not also have databases tables. 
I want to set Meta info for that pages. 
How can I programmatically set Meta for that pages by identifying loaded URL in Browser dynamically.

Pages urls like -

http://example.com/contacts/

http://example.com/questions/

http://example.com/customer/account/create/

http://example.com/customer/account/forgotpassword/

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Need to override Layout file for that & Use http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35845/how-to-add-change-meta-tags-specific-to-the-contacts-page

Answer (score 1):

Use your theme file local.xml

example for contact page

```
<contacts_index_index>
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle"><title>Title</title></action>
    <action method="setDescription"><description>Description</description></action>
    <action method="setKeywords"><keywords>Keywords</keywords></action>
</reference></contacts_index_index>
```